# Pythonanywhere socketio alternative

Tags: socket.io, webrtc, pythonanywhere

so I recently got started with pythonanywhere but was bummed out to notice there is no web socket support. My question today isn't about possible hacks but instead possible alternatives. Is there a solutions I could use for free or close to free specifically for carrying out my socketio microservice? It would only need to setup the socket since I would be using socketio P2P functionality, therefore this server would only be a fallback in the eventuality the client's browser does not support WebRTC. All replies are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the socketio docs, it uses websockets when they're available, but uses long polling when websockets are not available. If you only need the connection for a short time, then long polling is fine on PythonAnywhere.

Comment: I see. Thing is I tried it once but a got a connection error I don't know what's up with that but that time I wasn't using socketio p2p so I'll definitely try again. Thanks. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I've been doing some digging and it seems the error I got previously was due to the fact that pythonanywhere uses a nginx for routing which means the app is hidden behind a reverse proxy and to overcome this I would need to change pythonanywhere nginx config. I doubt I'll be getting that anytime soon.